# jre 1.6 check and progress bar in inno

Tags: inno-setup, java

I want to check whether hre 1.6 or higher is installed or not. If installed I want to progress my application. If not installed , I want to install jre-6u17-windows-i586-s.exe after successfully installing jre , my control not returns to inno again. Please send a inno script for that.

best regards

SOumen

Comment: Hi Soumen, stackoverflow.com is not a place to ask for these kind of favors. Try to break your order in two technical questions. For example a) how to check using inno script if JRE 1.6 or higher is installer on a machine and b) how to run installation of JRE 1.6 ver 17 from inno script?

Answer (score 3):

For the [FILES] section:

```
[Files]
Source: "jre-6u17-windows-i586-s.exe"; DestDir: "{app}\JRE 1.6"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist
```

For the [CODE] section:

```
[Code]
Function JREInstallPrompt:Boolean;
begin
  if ((msgBox ('Do you want to install JRE 1.6?',mbinformation,mb_YesNo)=idYes)) then
   begin
     msgBox ('JRE 1.6 will being installing now. Please do not restart the machine or log off until it is complete!',mbinformation,mb_OK);
     Result:=True;
   end
 else Result:=False;
end;

Function JREVerifyInstall:Boolean;
begin
 if ((RegValueExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft','InstallerVersion')) or (JREInstallPrompt=False)) then //Exists or do not install
   Result:=False
 else Result:=True;
end;
```

And for the RUN section:

```
[Run]
;SQL Server Express 2005 Installer
Filename: "{app}\JRE 1.6\jre-6u17-windows-i586-s.exe"; WorkingDir: {app}\JRE 1.6; StatusMsg: Installing Java Runtime Environment... Please Wait...;Check:JREVerifyInstall
```

Hopefully that will get you pointed in the right direction.